# layout, layout-large, layout-normal and so on

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, layout

I restart to develop an app which I stop to work on it years ago.

I would to move from Eclipse to Android Studio, but before I tried to check if it works with the Nexus5 I actually have. The app was tested on Nexus S.

After compiling and starting I get a lot of NullPointerException and I saw that depends on different findViewById not resolved.

I was using only the res/layout folder.

I tryed to copy that folder to a new folder named res/layout-large and all works fine.

My questions are:

- Is there no way to use only res/layout ?
- I have to rename it to res/layout-normal because res/layout isn't anymore the default layout folder, or not?
- Do I need to introduce also the other folders (res/layout-normal and so on) ?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: Please share some code snippets. This doesn't seem to be an issue with layout structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-large` `-xlarge` and so on have been deprecated for quite some time.

The documentation is not always up to date but it is recommended to use `-sw<N>dp` instead, for example `layout-sw600dp`

You don't **have** to use anything else than the base selector (layout, values, drawable, etc) for any kind of resource, so your problem seems to be in how you declare and use these resources.

Comment: But in my project there was only res/layout, and the findElementById returns null. After creating res/layout-large (with the same files inside) it works. Which could be the problem with my res/layout ?

Comment: Without seeing your project, I have no way to know.  A build plugin bug seems rather unlikely since this a base part of any app ..  (however, I don't know which build plugin you are still using on eclipse -_-  )  .  So there must be something fishy in the code or layout structure ..  Again no selector is the default and this is not going to change

Comment: Thankyou, I really don't know what I've changed, but now seems to work. I also moved my project to Android Studio, got and solved some problems and now I can start to renew my app!!